# generate variable names (something like get())

Tags: r, function, variable-assignment

How can i substitute this code with a loop?

```
m1 <- ggplot(foo)
m2 <- ggplot(foo)
...
m9 <- ggplot(foo)
```

I guess i need something like `get()` to replace magic(), But get did not work here.

```
for (i in 1:9){
  magic(i) <- ggplot(foo)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list:

```
out <- list()

for (i in 1:9){
  out[[i]] <- ggplot(foo)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
p <- qplot(data = mtcars, wt, mpg)
for(i in 1:9) assign(paste0("m",i),p)
ls()
 [1] "i"  "m1" "m2" "m3" "m4" "m5" "m6" "m7" "m8" "m9" "p"
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
for (i in 1:9) {
  name <- paste("m", i, sep="")
  assign(name, ggplot(foo))
}
```